# bugzilla: how to create custom field in advanced search to search custom field created through admin

Tags: perl, search, customization, bugzilla

I know that Bugzilla 3.0 and up supports the creation of custom fields for your bugs and that this can be done through admin.

My question was, is there any way that I would be able to create a custom field in the advanced search that would be able to search for the bugs that had the values from that custom field.

I know the current bugzilla supported solution is to use the boolean search under custom search which is on the advanced search page, but I would like to create my own custom field.

The current modifications I have done so far have been through the form.tmpl file under the custom folder which is a copy of the default folder. I have managed to play around with the default fields, but no luck in creating a custom field.

Source: http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.18/html/cust-templates.html

I found another source: http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/Adding-Custom-Field-drop-downs-to-Advanced-Search-Page-td80291.html

That somewhat directed me towards understanding how to solve the issue. As of now, it appears I need to go to the search.pm file under bugzilla folder which is responsible for the queries that generate the reports for the searches. This is described in the file itself, and the https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Search.pm source.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can manage custom bugzilla fields through Search.pm file, which is inside the Bugzilla folder.

for that, you need to push the custom select fields into the legal fields array and loop through that,

```
my @legal_fields = (<enter whatever legal fields, you have with the comma seperator>);

push(@legal_fields, map { $_->name } @select_fields);

foreach my $field ($params->param()) {
    if (lsearch(\@legal_fields, $field) != -1) {
        push(@specialchart, [$field, "anyexact",
                         join(',', $params->param($field))]);
    }
}
```

select_fields array should contains your custom fields. and legal_fields contains your legal fields.